# Optional in UserRepository causes authentication mechanism to break

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-security, option-type

I am using `spring boot` along with `spring security` and in my `UsersRepository`, I have the following code:

```java
public interface UsersRepository<T extends Users> extends CoreRepository<Users> {

    Optional<Users> findByEmail(String email);

}
```

And, in my `WebSecurityConfig` in the `configure` method, I have the following:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
         auth.userDetailsService(
                username -> {
                    return usersRepository.findByEmail(username)
                            .orElseThrow(
                                    () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Account not found for " + username)
                            )
                }
        );
        
    }
```

This pops up with this error:
[image: Try/Catch usage error]

When I add a try/catch (which really shouldn't be necessary?), I get the following error:
[image: bad type error]

I know that this is because the method in  the `UsersRepository` is declared as `Optional<Users>` - and you can retrieve the object by using `.get()` after the object is retrieved - but that is not what we are doing here.

I need to pass an implementation of `UserDetails` to the `auth.userDetailsService()` call.

What do I need to do to satisfy this?

**Update**

Here are the errors returned from the compiler:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/sitebuild/src/main/java/com/zev/installations/config/WebSecurityConfig.java:[62,33] incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      java.lang.Object cannot be converted to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails)
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am using IntelliJ Idea - added tag. This behavior occurs in Netbeans too, so I am not sure it is an IDE issue

Comment: You aren't allowed to throw an exception in a lambda (although this is a runtime exception), which is probably why it barfs. If you write the same code in a private method in your class which you then call from the lambda it will probably work. Also make sure that your `Users` object implements `UserDetails` or convert it to a plain `User` object from Spring Security.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to satisfy UserDetails contract:

```
static class Users extends User {
    // ... Implement constructors 
}
```

With this small change the code compiles OK.

Another, is to use Spring Security provided User instead of Users.